# Setting uibutton frame not working

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, frame

I have values in dictionaries that will make a frame of a uibutton

```
tags =         (
                    {
            height = "15.513672";
            text = jeans;
            width = "39.808105";
            x = "225.500000";
            y = "265.000000";
        },
                    {
            height = "15.513672";
            text = jacket;
            width = "44.080078";
            x = "190.000000";
            y = "156.500000";
        }
    );
```

I set the frame of uibuttons with the values from the dictionaries

```
for (int i = 0; i<[tags count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"adding tags");

    NSMutableDictionary *propertiesdict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    propertiesdict = [[tags objectAtIndex:i] mutableCopy];

    float x = [[dict objectForKey:@"x"] floatValue];
    float y = [[dict objectForKey:@"y"] floatValue];
    float width = [[dict objectForKey:@"width"] floatValue];
    float height = [[dict objectForKey:@"height"] floatValue];

    NSString *title = [dict objectForKey:@"text"];

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 2.5;
    //button.alpha = 0.9;
    [button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13]];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor viewFlipsideBackgroundColor]];
    button.tag = i;
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(tappedOnTag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [tagsView addSubview:button];
}
```

After adding the buttons to the subview, the NSLog shows that each button has a frame (0,0,0,0) which differs from when I set the frame in the for loop.

```
2015-10-15 12:25:17.787 kyss[1018:316548] tapped on tags view. Number of subviews = 2. Subviews: (
    "<UIButton: 0x15f732330; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x15f72eb60>>",
    "<UIButton: 0x15f6d10e0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x15f6b3790>>"
)
```

Comment: Are the values of `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height` correct inside the loop?

Comment: @rmaddy yes, the NSLog shows 2015-10-15 12:52:22.447 kyss[1044:324386] adding tags
2015-10-15 12:52:22.447 kyss[1044:324386] properties dictionary = {
    height = "15.513672";
    text = jacket;
    width = "44.080078";
    x = "190.000000";
    y = "156.500000";
}

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Are the actual `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height` variables correct? You seem to be logging `properiesDict` (which is created from `tags`) but you get the values from `dict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at the code...

```
for (int i = 0; i<[tags count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"adding tags");

    NSMutableDictionary *propertiesdict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    propertiesdict = [[tags objectAtIndex:i] mutableCopy];
```

You create a new dictionary and immediately overwrite the reference with an item from the tags array.

```
    float x = [[dict objectForKey:@"x"] floatValue];
    float y = [[dict objectForKey:@"y"] floatValue];
    float width = [[dict objectForKey:@"width"] floatValue];
    float height = [[dict objectForKey:@"height"] floatValue];
```

You reference `dict`, which isn't defined in the code you posted.  It's safe to assume that it's not the same as `propertiesdict`, so you're getting `nil` references, thus the value 0 for each assignment.

```
    NSString *title = [dict objectForKey:@"text"];
```

Again with the `dict`.

```
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 2.5;
    //button.alpha = 0.9;
    [button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13]];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor viewFlipsideBackgroundColor]];
    button.tag = i;
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(tappedOnTag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [tagsView addSubview:button];
}
```

The rest of the code is ok.

Anyway, your problem is referencing the wrong dictionary.  Did you not notice that the title is wrong too?

Comment: How can you notice the wrong title when the button's frame is 0,0,0,0?

Comment: He could only tell that the frame is all zeros by checking in the debugger.  The same debugger would give him the title, if he checked for it.